# Get warning deprecation : moment.updateLocale(); at moment-with-locales js

Tags: javascript

I got warning deprecation in firefox when i use moment-with-locales.min.js and can't to use local languange with this warning .

Here is the message from console :

```
      "Deprecation warning: use moment.updateLocale(localeName, config) to change an existing locale. moment.defineLocale(localeName, config) should only be used for creating a new locale See http://momentjs.com/guides/#/warnings/define-locale/ for more info."
```

How i can fix this ?
Thank.

Comment: What happens when you use `moment.updateLocale(localName, config)` as instructed?

Comment: The problem is that warning at moment-with-locales.min.js and very very many defineLocale function at those js, so imposibble for me to change all defineLocale function to updateLocale

Comment: I'd misunderstood, I thought you were calling the method yourself. The issue appears to have been fixed in https://github.com/ffrgb/meshviewer/issues/96 are you using an up to date version?

Answer (score 2):

Find the script which is calling the moment.js that throws this warning. Edit your script and search for "**.defineLocale(**" then replace with "**.updateLocale(**".

Answer (score 2):

At the time of config the locale, if it was as follows:

```
moment.locale("fr", fr);
```

change it to:

```
moment.locale("fr");
```

You also no longer need to add language file directly to your document.